# counting individual characters in c

Tags: c, cs50, counting

I’m working on a project called readability. the user input a text and the code should then use the coleman-liau function to determine the reading level. But in order to use this fuktion you have to determine the number of words, letters and sentences. Right now I’m busy counting the letters. So I wanted to ask how to count individual characters in c. right now this is my code:

```
int count_letters (string text)
{
    int count_letters = 0;
    int numb = 0;
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(text); i < n; i++)
    {
        if (text[i] != '')
        {
            count_letters++;
        }
    }
    return count_letters;
}
```

Comment: Using an empty character constant in `text[i] != ''` doesn't make sense. What do you want to do here?

Comment: i dont really know. i googled how to count in c and this was the answer. so i just copied it without understanding why. i know this wasnt the smartest desicion.

Comment: `#include <ctype.h>` and then use `isalpha`. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalpha/

Comment: Copying and using code you don't understand is not a good strategy. Especially if you copy it wrong. The character is more likely a space and not empy: `text[i] = ' '`. Note the space inside the single quote.

Comment: There is no question in your post. Ask a specific question.

Comment: I suppose the test was intended not to count spaces, which means it's **if (text[i] != ' ')** @MikeCAT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use `isalpha()` or "improvise".

This will work for the [*ASCII*](http://www.asciitable.com/) character set:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int count_letters(const char *str)
{
    int count = 0, i = 0;

    for (; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if ((str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z') || (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z'))
        {
            /* any character within this range is either a lower or upper case letter */
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char *str = "Hello\n world hello123@";

    printf("%d\n", count_letters(str));

    return 0;
}
```

or use `isalpha()`, also supports your current locale.

```
#include <ctype.h>

int count_letters(const char *str)
{
    int count = 0, i = 0;

    for (; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (isalpha((unsigned char)str[i]))
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

EDIT: As [Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4756299/andrew-henle) mentioned, to be pedantic, you better pass an `unsigned char` as argument to `isalpha()` to avoid any undefined behavior that might arise due to the signed type of `str`.

Comment: Pedantically, `isalpha()` isn't guaranteed to work if `char` is signed and you pass such a `char`.  [Per **7.4 Character handling `<ctype.h>`**, paragraph 1 of the C 11 standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.4p1): "In all cases the argument is an int, the value of which shall be representable as an unsigned char or shall equal the value of the macro EOF. If the argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined."  Why? A `signed char` is sign-extended when it's promoted to the `int` value that's passed to `isalpha()` and that isn't "representable as an unsigned char".

Comment: So to be strictly conforming to standard C, you can only pass an `unsigned char` to functions like `isalpha()`.  C is full of such weird corner cases that don't seem to make much sense.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I've added that in my answer.